# Can't figure out why ScriptEngine engine is null in code

Tags: javascript, java, java-7

This is some of the code I'm running for a MapleStory server. Whenever a script for an event like talking to an NPC is supposed to occur, this script will be run to create a scripting path for whatever script is being called up (NPC, portal, event etc.).

I am also using jdk1.7.0_80

```
lang-java
package scripting;

import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.script.Invocable; 
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import client.MapleClient; 
import tools.FileoutputUtil;

public abstract class AbstractScriptManager {

    private static final ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager(null);

    protected Invocable getInvocable(String path, MapleClient c) {
        return getInvocable(path, c, false);
    }

    protected Invocable getInvocable(String path, MapleClient c, boolean npc) {
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            path = "scripts/" + path;
            ScriptEngine engine = null;

            if (c != null) {
                engine = c.getScriptEngine(path);
            }
            if (engine == null) {
                File scriptFile = new File(path);
                if (!scriptFile.exists()) {
                    return null;
                }
                engine = sem.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
                if (c != null) {
                    c.setScriptEngine(path, engine);
                }
                fr = new FileReader(scriptFile);
                engine.eval(fr);
            } else if (c != null && npc) {
                c.getPlayer().dropMessage(-1, "You already are talking to this NPC. Use @ea if this is 
                not intended.");
            }
            return (Invocable) engine;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error executing script. Path: " + path + "\nException " + e);
            FileoutputUtil.log(FileoutputUtil.ScriptEx_Log, "Error executing script. Path: " + path + 
            "\nException " + e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fr != null) {
                    fr.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ignore) {

            }
        }
    } 
}
```

**This is the bat error I receive:**

> Error executing script. Path: scripts/event/someEvent.js Exception
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(java.io.Reader)" because "engine" is null

These errors are thrown whenever I try to interact with something that utilizes this method (i.e. clicking NPC or on server start-up when some scripts are run).

Comment: What version of Java are you running? Note that JavaScript was removed in Java 15. [JDK-8236933](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/15-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8236933): *"The Nashorn JavaScript script engine, its APIs, and the `jjs` tool have been removed. The engine, the APIs, and the tool were deprecated for removal in Java 11 with the express intent to remove them in a future release."*

Comment: I'm using Java 7 for this project

Comment: Oracle JDK 7 or OpenJDK 7 or some other build?

Comment: Try running the following code. I bet it doesn't print anything, meaning that the Java build you're running on doesn't have any script engines. `for (ScriptEngineFactory factory : sem.getEngineFactories()) { System.out.println(factory.getEngineName() + " " + factory.getEngineVersion() + " " + factory.getNames()); }`. --- My Oracle JDK 8 prints `Nashorn`, my OpenJDK 7 prints nothing.

Comment: The bat didn't output anything but I am also using jdk1.7.0_80

Comment: Thank you @Andreas I forgot I had other versions of Java also installed so my pathing was not set up correctly. It works as intended now

Comment: [*Nashorn removal: GraalVM to the rescue!*](https://medium.com/graalvm/nashorn-removal-graalvm-to-the-rescue-d4da3605b6cb)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` occurs because the Java Runtime you're using doesn't have a "JavaScript" Script Engine installed, causing `sem.getEngineByName("JavaScript")` to return `null`.

That was verified (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747123/cant-figure-out-why-scriptengine-engine-is-null-in-code?noredirect=1#comment116262720_65747123)) by running the following code:

```java
ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
List<ScriptEngineFactory> factories = sem.getEngineFactories();
for (ScriptEngineFactory factory : factories)
    System.out.println(factory.getEngineName() + " " + factory.getEngineVersion() + " " + factory.getNames());
if (factories.isEmpty())
    System.out.println("No Script Engines found");
```

When I run this on various Java implementations on Windows 10, I get the following results:

```
OpenJDK jdk1.7.0_75:
  No Script Engines found

Oracle jdk1.7.0_80:
  Mozilla Rhino 1.7 release 3 PRERELEASE [js, rhino, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]

Oracle jdk1.8.0_181:
  Oracle Nashorn 1.8.0_181 [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]

Oracle jdk-9.0.4:
  Oracle Nashorn 9.0.4 [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]

OpenJDK jdk-11.0.2:
  Oracle Nashorn 11.0.2 [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]

AdoptOpenJDK jdk-14.0.2+12:
  Oracle Nashorn 14.0.2 [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]

AdoptOpenJDK jdk-15.0.1+9:
  No Script Engines found
```

As you can see, the OpenJDK version of Java 7 doesn't have a JavaScript engine, because the Mozilla Rhino library isn't open-source. You need the Oracle version of Java 7 to get the JavaScript engine.

You can also see that JavaScript was removed in Java 15, as documented in the [JDK 15 Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/15-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8236933):

> The Nashorn JavaScript script engine, its APIs, and the `jjs` tool have been removed. The engine, the APIs, and the tool were deprecated for removal in Java 11 with the express intent to remove them in a future release. See JDK-8236933

Comment: Can you update the question for Java18? And does Rhino works in 18 too?

Comment: OpenJDK Java 19 does NOT have it. Sorry

Comment: I am using java 20. It does not include javascript engine. What do I have to do to get javascript functionality working?

Comment: Any updates that could get GraalJS working?  I have js.exe in:  /c/graaljs-community-jvm-23.1.2-windows-amd64/graaljs-community-23.1.2-windows-amd64/bin/js.exe

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with JDK 17 and `lib rhino.js.engine-1.7.71.jar`.

I added

```
org.mozilla.javascript-1.7.5.jar
```

to my classpath too. That solved the error.